# Typo3: Load data from array into Fluid template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I'm trying to output data from a TypoScript array inside my Fluid template. This is what I have added this to my template's setup:

```
images {
  10 = url/to/image/1.jpg
  20 = url/to/image/2.jpg
  30 = url/to/image/3.jpg
}
```

This is what my template looks like:

```
<f:for each="{images}" as="image">
    <img src="{image} />
</f:for>
```

However, no data is being displayed. I even copied the example given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393091/typoscript-arrays-and-using-them-in-fluid), but still it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? My Typo3 version is 6.1

Comment: What is the context? Are you inside your own extension with this template?

Comment: Please add some more context info: Is the template rendered using a `FLUIDTEMPLATE` content object or is it rendered by an extension controller? Where exactly did you put the TypoScript for the images? Is it in the `variables` section of a `FLUIDTEMPLATE` object?

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to output the settings with the Debug-ViewHelper, so you can check if {images} is in fact an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a syntax error (missing closing quote in `image` property):

```
<f:for each="{images}" as="image">
    <img src="{image}" />
</f:for>
```